# jquery conflict

Tags: jquery

I have a problem regarding jquery,
I have written a plugin in wordpress and included jquery and found that it conflicting with my wordpress jquery.
I have used jquery no.conflict but it is not working.
Is there any thing other than jquery.noconflict.

Best wishes

Answer (score 3):

Did I read that right: You have a problem, because you're developing a Wordpress plugin and you included the JQuery library even though Wordpress already includes it? And now you are wondering about conflicts?

You should use the version included by Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like version included in wordpress - you can change it I hope.

Anyway, you can have 2 different versions of jQuery on the page, but the actual will be last version.

For example:

1. Wordpress has jq1.4
2. Wordpress has code for 1.4
3. You want 1.6.2
4. You write code for 1.6.2
5. To avoid conflicts your code must be at the bottom of the page, after wordpress js code.